# Alignment spacing for negatives - Why am I unable to properly align my equations?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations

Although I searched the Web and indeed found an answer here, I still seem unable to address my issue of aligning two rows in my step-by-step process for solving a very basic equation. Just in case it matters, I am using MathJax, which is a JavaScript library that renders LaTeX in various forms of output (in my case, as MathML and HTML/CSS).

My code:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    \hphantom{-} 9 + x &=& 12   \\
    -9 \hphantom{+ x} &=& -9    \\
    \hline                      \\
    \implies x &=& 3
\end{eqnarray}
```

My goal is to get the "9" to align in the first two rows, however, the `\hphantom` macro in the first row isn't adjusting the `9 + x = 12` at all. I came up with the code using the help of people who answered a similar alignment question elsewhere here.

I noted that when I reversed the first two rows in my code, `\hphantom` did indeed align the 9 correctly.

I would appreciate anyone helping me determine if there is an issue with my LaTeX. If not, I can investigate the HTML/CSS layout issues.

Comment: Yes, it matters because MathJaX is not really TeX, it only uses TeX for markup. Though, you can try `\hphantom{{} + x}`. And do not use `eqnarray`: [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: Thank you, @Qrrbrbirlbel, your suggestion addressed the problem perfectly. I'll better keep in mind that MathJax may have discrepancies down the line, as well. EDIT: also, I wasn't aware of the issues of eqnarray, thank you for the reference!

Comment: Summarize your findings (and the comments) into an answer, and later accept it to close the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Qrrbrbirlbel, I was able to address the problem by using: `\hphantom{{} + x}`. So, if you're a MathJax user, this does address the issue.

Although I have yet to turn up on the Web further information as to *why* this alteration fixes things, it's nevertheless useful to keep in mind.

Comment: The spacing rules are in the TeXbook.  `+` is class `\mathbin` when between to ordinary (`\mathord`) symbols such as `x`, `9` or `{}`, otherwise it is an ordinary symbol.  No spacing is placed between mathord's, whereas Ord-Bin-Ord gets extra spacing around the binary operator.  The reason that a unitary + should be placed right up by the symbol it affects, whereas a binary one should be spaced off from its symbols.